# Библиотека `hostpolicy.dll` не найдена

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, config

Из процесса #1 мне нужно запустить процесс #2. Сам процесс #2 – это моё приложение .NET Core. Для удобства запуска я добавил ссылку на приложение #2 в приложение #1 (Visul Studio) – теперь они в 1-й папке. Когда запускаю процесс #1 всё хорошо, но при запуске процесса #2 мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in '<.NET data path>'.
```

Я почитал про это ошибку и все как один говорили, что нужно добавить файл `<application #2 name>.runtimeconfig.json` *вручную* внутрь папки с приложением #1. И это работает, но брать и вручную перетаскивать конфиг... это как-то не очень. Причём если изменить конфиг приложения #2 внутри папки приложения #2, то его копия внутри папки приложения #1 меняться не будет, т. е. нужно заново его перетаскивать.

Почему вообще происходят такие ошибки в 1-м из лучших IDE для C#? Как это исправить, чтобы таких проблем больше не возникало?

Comment: Вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085430/the-library-hostpolicy-dll-was-not-found) не помогло?

Comment: Кажется, [баг](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569)

Comment: @aepot там где баг, я про эту ошибку и узнал, щас пробую решение из ваше 1-го комментария

Comment: @aepot но 2-й вопрос всё ещё актуален

Comment: Чтобы ответить на второй вопрос, нужен воспроизводимый пример и шаги воспроизведения конкретно для вашего  случая.

Comment: @aepot нет, я имел ввиду в самой студии создать какой-нибудь скрипт, который будет копировать `runtimeconfig.json`

Comment: @aepot в моём случае я просто скопировал его)

Comment: *создать какой-нибудь скрипт* - Не имею практики в этом, но если по хардкору, можно свой VSIX плагин написать и прикрутить. Еще [вот такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463758/how-to-create-a-simple-build-script-for-visual-studio-from-the-command-line) можно рассмотреть.

Comment: @aepot к сожалению, я проверил ваш 1-й комментарий и он не работает, т. к. в моём `.csproj` по умолчанию установлено `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`, т. е.данное решение "встроено" в мой проект при его создании

Comment: @return В студии есть `Pre-build` и `Post-build` евенты, в которых можете делать что угодно до и после сборки проекта.

Comment: @ГеннадийП напишите в ответ скрипт (или что там?). я просто ни бе ни ме в программировании, связанном с VS.

Comment: @return Там по сути обычные DOS-команды. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box